# How do I tell yum not to remove itself?

Tags: linux, centos, yum

When I run this command

```
$ sudo yum erase git make gcc g++ zlib1g-dev libssl-dev wget subversion file python apt-utils binfmt-support vim apt-file xz-utils sudo subversion zlib1g-dev gawk flex unzip bzip2 gettext build-essential libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev binutils cpp psmisc docbook-to-man gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Trying to remove "systemd", which is protected
Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected
```

But those aren't packages I gave. I tried `-t` to tolerate errors, and `-x yum -x systemd` to specifically exclude those two, but it still gave the error.

```
$ sudo yum -x yum -x systemd erase git make gcc ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to remove some essential packages which would break your system if removed:

- `python`: `yum` is written in Python, so this package cannot be removed, or else you lose your package manager.
- `binutils`: `systemd` needs this package, and systemd is your init system, which is crucial to using CentOS 7.
- `gawk`: A ton of things depend on `gawk`, including both `yum` and `systemd`.

You cannot remove those critical system packages, so exclude `python`, `binutils`, and `gawk` from your list of packages to remove.

Note that you are still trying to remove some useful packages like `gettext`, `sudo`, and `wget`, which might not horribly break your system but could reduce usability.

Comment: It still gave the error. Isn't there a way to tell it to ignore any packages that `yum` depends on?

Comment: @Chloe: Reload my answer.  I forgot to address `systemd`'s dependency on `binutils`.

Comment: It still complains about both of them.

Comment: Update your question with the current command your using

Comment: @Chloe: How about now?

Comment: I just kept running it one package at a time (well maybe 3 at a time) until it worked. I really wanted a way for it to figure it out automatically. Yes, I should not remove `sudo` either. It's a Vagrant box so it's pretty disposable. I want to keep the virtual disk as small as possible. If I need one of those, I'll just re-install it.

Comment: perhaps you should use cloud images - just a search away: centos cloud vagrant. - http://cloud.centos.org/centos/7/vagrant/x86_64/images/

Answer (score -2):

try  $sudo yum remove @groupname

or

$sudo yum groupremove groupname

When you tell yum to remove a package group, it will remove every package in that group, even if those packages are members of other package groups or dependencies of other installed packages. However, you can instruct yum to remove only those packages which are not required by any other packages or groups by adding the groupremove_leaf_only=1 directive to the [main] section of the /etc/yum.conf configuration file.

groupremove_leaf_only=value

…where value is one of:
0 — yum should not check the dependencies of each package when removing a package group. With this setting, yum removes all packages in a package group, regardless of whether those packages are required by other packages or groups.

groupremove_leaf_only=0 is the default.

1 — yum should check the dependencies of each package when removing a package group, and remove only those packages which are not required by any other package or group.

Comment: i do not get it

Comment: Could you add some more detail such as what this does.